# Getting ID of clicked TableRow in Titanium Alloy?

Tags: backbone.js, data-binding, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm new to Titanium and to Backbone. I've worked with JS frameworks before (most familiar with Knockout.js), but Backbone, and the way it works with Alloy, is taking some getting used to.

I want to do something very simple. I have a collection bound to a TableView. All I want to do is get the data associated with a particular row when it is clicked.

The should be trivial, but all the docs seem to assume you know how to use Alloy already!

**Model**

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            subject: "text",
            convo_id: "integer",
            created: "text",
            modified: "text"
        },
...
```

**View**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="convosView" title="Conversations">
        <ScrollView id="convoScrollList">
            <TableView id="convoList" dataCollection="convos">
                <TableViewRow onClick="rowClick">
                    <View class="convoRow">
                        <Label class="convoTitle" text="{subject}" />
                        <Label class="convoDate" text="{created}" />
                        <View class="rowArrow" />
                    </View>
                </TableViewRow>
            </TableView>
        </ScrollView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**Controller**

```
var conversations = Alloy.Collections.convos;
conversations.fetch();

function rowClick(e) {
    alert(e.created);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the sample port of the ti fugutive app I created. The basic idea is to save the id of the model in the table row and then on click, fetch the model.

```
$.table.addEventListener('click', function(_e) {
    var detailController = Alloy.createController('FugitiveDetail', {
        parentTab : $.fugitiveTab,
        data : fugitiveCollection.get(_e.rowData.model)
    });
    $.fugitiveTab.open(detailController.getView());
});
```

the table row is constructed like this

```
<Alloy>
    <!-- have to use alloy_id since I did not specify an id in the schema -->
    <TableViewRow id="row" dataId="" model="{alloy_id}">
        <View class="vgroup">
            <Label id="name" text="{name}"/>
            <Label id="address" text="{address}"/>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Ah so you still have to hook up the property you want to retrieve in the XML (in this case via `model="{alloy_id}"`). My assumption with data-binding was that this sort of thing wasn't necessary. That the representation of a model in the view was intrinsically tied to the data object. It appears in Alloy, this is not the case.

Comment: You still need to bind the field, but theoretically the framework could determine the idAttribute and set it in the view

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
function rowClick(e) {
    alert(e.rowData);
};
```

you could aslo get the index as follows

```
function rowClick(e) {
        alert(e.index);
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: This is partially correct. The index definitely works, but e.rowData only returns parameters that are present in the XML declaration. I'm wanting to return the actual model data to which the rows are bound.